# q point keeps shifting when there is input signal

Tags: transistors, amplifier

Why is that, even at transistor idle conditions, where my q point is exactly midway in the transistor loadline, when i start to inject ac signal at the input, the q point starts to shift somewhere else, therefore causing clipping. So this means that the act of inputting an ac signal sometimes causes the q point to shift naturally? Are there any counter measures against this? (Like compensating by means of finding a new q point wherein at idle conditions, it is exactly not at the middle anymore)

I have a 12 Vcc supply, emitter voltage is at .97 Volts, and so the collector voltage should be at

(12-.97)(1/2) = 5.5 V

which is in accordance here in my simulation

[image]

[image: and yet, after injecting an ac signal, clipping occurs]

Here is the schematic [image]

Comment: Show the schematic, this time *without* all those annoying meters and wierd blocks cluttering it up, which is why I have ignored some of your other questions.  The operating point is probably changing because there is some rectification going on shifting things.  Put another way, the native signal decay from high to center and low to center aren't symmetric.

Comment: all annoying meters and weird blocks remove http://puu.sh/1u81t

Comment: No, that silly scope-looking thing at top right is still there.  If it were connected between the output and ground it might make some sense, but I don't see what the point is of measuring between the output and the input, if that's what it's actually doing.

Comment: Also, the base of the transistor should be connected to the junction of R4 and R6, but it's probably not since there doesn't appear to be a junction dot there.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49661/signal-clipped-despite-q-point-is-middle

When the Q point is in the DC middle, it's not in the AC middle. That is covered in that question.

Comment: What is the stage designed to do? Will circuit be in a class A audio home system, Class C critical air to air comms, where and what will the stage be used for will be the basic concern first. Degeneration on the emitter lead, is that always bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the correct Q-point is 6.5V, not 5.5V.  The Q-point should be roughly halfway between Vcc and the DC emitter voltage.  Halfway between 12V and 1V is 6.5V, not 5.5V.

At 5.5V, the negative swing is just 5.5V - 1V = 4.5V while the positive swing is 12V - 5.5V = 6.5V.  This is why the negative peak clips first.

UPDATE:  I wrote the above under the assumption that, as in the previous circuits the OP has asked about, the emitter resistor is AC bypassed.  Now that the schematic has been posted, I see that there is no emitter bypass capacitor in this circuit.

With the emitter resistor bypassed, the emitter is at AC ground and this simplifies the Q-point calculation.  Without bypass, the calculation is more complex.

When the transistor is saturated, the voltage between collector and emitter is roughly zero.  Thus, the emitter current is:

\$i_{E(max)} = \dfrac{V_{CC}}{R_5 + R_7} =  17mA\$

Thus, the lowest voltage the collector can fall to is:

\$v_{C(min)} = i_{E(max)} \cdot R_7 = 1.56V \$

So, a rough estimate of the Q-point collector voltage is:

\$(12 - 1.56)/2 + 1.56 = 6.8V \$

However, this is an iterative process.  When you change the value of the collector or emitter resistor, the above calculations change so the idea is to calculate a reasonable starting point, simulate to see where you are, and adjust / tweak as necessary.

UPDATE 2:  For a detailed analysis of the calculation of clipping levels, see [Single Stage BJT Amplifier Clipping Levels](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mleach/ece3050/notes/bjt/bjtclipsu08.pdf) by W. M. Leach.